# a question should be closed as duplicate not off-topic

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, scope

I saw this question :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27725287/i-need-some-assistance-on-an-assigment-i-got-on-high-school-in-java-programming
it's put on hold as off-topic but I think maybe it's better to be put on hold as duplicate of:
[converting seconds to hours,minutes, and seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24590769/converting-seconds-to-hours-minutes-and-seconds)
but maybe the voters thought that because the OP wants help in school assignment, am I wrong or not ?

Answer (score 4):

The reason we don't delete duplicates is so that they serve as signposts. There are many ways to formulate a problem.

**The question at hand here, in its [current form](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27725287/3) is not a good signpost.** The title is "i need some assistance on an assigment i got on high school in java programming". The text of the question itself is not all that clear either. So to make a good signpost, it would have to be edited.

The OP (again, in the current form of the question) gives a problem statement and a bit of code but does not specify exactly where there's a problem. Is it with the random number generation? With the conversion to the time format? Both? Something else? Until this is clarified *in the question* (not in comments) it is not clear what it *may* be a duplicate of.

Comment: the question is clear, if it was unclear it would be put on hold as unclear not off-topic

Comment: Going by the logic in your comment here: if the question was a duplicate (as you assert in your question) it would have been put on hold as a duplicate, not as off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

It was closed with a custom (rather sarcastic) reason, which defaults to "off-topic".

It certainly seems the close reason was due to it being a "give me teh codez" question as you suspected. I'm not sure its worth the effort of re-opening and closing as a duplicate (though it sure looks like one).

You should at least post a comment with a link to the duplicate. Doing so puts that question in the "Linked" section on the question page.

Comment: I thought of that but it's a homework, shouldn't he solve it by himself and we just help him when he tries his efforts, fails, and get stuck ?

Comment: @niceman Thats the concept. Its too bad many students don't understand thats how it should work.

Comment: ok then off-topic it is, do I delete this MSO question ?

Comment: @niceman You can, but you certainly don't have to. Given that theres an upvote on the other answer you might not be *able* to.

Comment: He has since shown some code and effort, and so now the question does in fact appear to be in the process of possibly being re-opened.